# mysql: I didn't update the table defining the trigger in the trigger, but i got the similar error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have three tables. They are called book, reader, borrow.

The function of my trigger: insert borrowing records into the borrow table. But before inserting, we have to check the status of the reader's library card and the status of the book. Only when they are all normal can we lend the book to the reader, that is, change the status of the borrowed book in the book table to "borrowed", and then insert the borrowing record into the borrow table. However, some errors occurred when updating the book table.

Please look at my note 1, which reported me such an error: [stored trigger is already used by statement which invoked stored trigger]. I know that the trigger of MySQL can't modify the defined table, so I think this error is very puzzling. Then I created a new account table and added the sentence marked in Note 2 to the trigger. It works properly. So this mistake really confused me.

I would be very grateful if you could help me. Followings is my code:

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_insert_borrow;
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_borrow BEFORE INSERT ON borrow
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE cst VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE b_cts VARCHAR(10);
    SELECT Card_status FROM reader WHERE read_no = NEW.read_no INTO cst;
    SELECT B_status FROM book WHERE book_no = NEW.book_no INTO b_cts;

    IF cst = 'loss' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '09000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'your card is lost……';
    ELSEIF b_cts = 'checked' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '09000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'the book you want has been checked out.';
    END IF;
        
        
     UPDATE book SET B_status = 'checked' WHERE book_no = NEW.book_no;      -- 1 
     
     UPDATE account SET total = total + 1000 WHERE id =1;               -- 2 
END;




-- test data
INSERT INTO borrow(read_no,book_no)VALUES('001','B17682');
```

Comment: Provide: CREATE TABLE for all tables; some initial sample data (2-3 rows) AS INSERT INTO, inserting query (present, but expand and add a query which fires SIGNAL) and final data state with explanations.

Comment: *`UPDATE account SET total = total + 1000 WHERE id =1;`* Maybe `= NEW.read_no`, not constant `1`?

Comment: @Akina  
Thank you for the ideas. Because this is just a small homework, there are not many tables and data involved, so I rebuilt the database and now it works normally.